# Image is missing

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have a 'test' database here:

http://www.bayingwolf.com/addRecords.asp

If you click on 'Add Records' a modal form pops-up and in the top right-hand corner of that form there should be a small PNG image of a 'X' to close the form.

It should look like this: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ (under 'Basic Modal Dialog' click 'Demo') with the X image in place.

In the download, the author uses the following on his index.html page:

```
<!-- preload the images --> 
<div style='display:none'>  
<img src='img/basic/x.png' alt='' />
```

and I have done exactly the same. When I open up his index.html page on my desktop, I can see the X image (I cannot open up my own page on my desktop because it's an ASP file) but, strangely, when I upload his index.html file to my server I cannot see the image.

I have double-checked the server path, and I have my X image in a folder called 'basic' which is in another folder called 'img'.

The CSS that governs the positioning of the image (in basic.css) is as follows:

```css
#simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {
    background: url(../img/basic/x.png) no-repeat; 
    width: 25px; 
    height: 29px; 
    display: inline; 
    z-index: 3200; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -15px; 
    right: -16px; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

My code is not a replica of the original code - I have a form on my page, but that should not affect the positioning of the X image.

Any suggestions please (I have been on this for at least two days!)?

Thanks

Comment: On your page there is only an empty anchor: `<a class="modalCloseImg simplemodal-close" title="Close"></a>` with no background set in CSS (`background: none`).

Comment: Maybe if you add ie_css only for ie6 then it should works.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you provided in your question is not present in your *basic.css* stylesheet. Instead, you have something like this:

```css
#simplemodal-container a {color:#ddd;} /* <-- bracket closed */


{background:url(x.png) no-repeat; /* <-- CSS parse error */
width:25px; 
height:29px; 
display:inline; 
z-index:3200; 
position:absolute; 
top:-15px; 
right:-16px; 
cursor:pointer;}
```

You probably didn't want to close this curly bracket after the `color` property. So clean up your CSS to this:

```css
#simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {
    color: #ddd;
    background: url(x.png) no-repeat;
    width: 25px; 
    height: 29px; 
    display: inline; 
    z-index: 3200; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -15px; 
    right: -16px; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging, You have an issue with your css. This css rule has no tag to go with. You should add the id or class to this rule. This may not fix everything but it's a step in the right direction.

I only took a quick glance but I think the class should be `.simplemodal-close`

```
#simplemodal-container a {color:#ddd;}


{background:url(x.png) no-repeat; 
width:25px; 
height:29px; 
display:inline; 
z-index:3200; 
position:absolute; 
top:-15px; 
right:-16px; 
cursor:pointer;}


#simplemodal-container h3 {color:#84b8d9;}
```

Should be:

```
#simplemodal-container a {color:#ddd;}


.simplemodal-close {
   background:url(x.png) no-repeat; 
   width:25px; 
   height:29px; 
   display:inline; 
   z-index:3200; 
   position:absolute; 
   top:-15px; 
   right:-16px; 
   cursor:pointer;}


#simplemodal-container h3 {color:#84b8d9;}
```

**EDIT:**
After even more investigation your `ie.css` is overriding your css in `basic.css` as well. so make sure that your `ie.css` is only loaded in IE and is also correct.

Additionally the url for the background is still incorrect it is looking for it in `http://www.bayingwolf.com/css/x.png` when it acttually lives in `http://www.bayingwolf.com/x.png` So your path should be `../x.png` eg:

```
.simplemodal-close {
    background:url(../x.png) no-repeat;
    ... /* rest of declarations */
}
```